# How to do the activate route in angular?

Tags: angular

My url:
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/#/Test?name=7779394

How can I get '7779394'?

I tried the following code:

```
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  this.ind = params.name;

  console.log("this.ind " + params.name);

});
```

But the result is undefined first, after undefined the function is run again and I got 7779394

But it should run one time only.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Post a complete minimal example. Your two lines of code are not sufficient to explain what happens.

Comment: Which lifecycle hook you're subscribing to ``queryParams``

Comment: i put it in OnInit

Comment: Have you tried params.get('name') instaed of params.name;

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

Here subscribing the `queryParams` may give `undefined` values sometimes if 'name' is not available in URL. It may be due to it is not defined before calling api.
Its natural and its a `BehaviourSubject` thing.

You can use `filter` to avoid undefined values.

```
constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute){}
ngOnInit() {
 const self = this;
this.route.queryParams.filter(params => params['name'] ).distinctUntilChanged().subscribe(params => {
self.nameVar= params['name']
 });
```

or,

```
this.route.queryParams.filter(params => params['name'])
.subscribe(params => {     
   self.nameVar = params['name'];
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of `RxJs` question.

What you have to do is filter the observable.

```js
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.activatedRoute.queryParams
  .pipe(
    map(params => params.name), // query only the name...
    filter(name => name !== undefined), // and filter it! (not to be undefined)
  )
  .subscribe(name => {
    // name will be real value(not undefined)
    this.ind = name;
    console.log("this.ind " + name);
  });
```

or if you need full `params` object...

```js
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.activatedRoute.queryParams
  .pipe(
    filter(params => params.name !== undefined), // params is always an object, so you don't have to check (params !== undefined).
  )
  .subscribe(params => {
    // params.name will be real value(not undefined)
    this.ind = params.name;
    console.log("this.ind " + params.name);
  });
```